# Image file with AngularJS and ASP NET MVC

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, image, upload

Please help me!
My Controller can't recent Image File from angular.

Here my angular file
[image: Here my angular file:]

Here my Controller
[image: Here my Controller]

Class Product:

```
    public class Product
{
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public byte[] Image { get; set; }
}
```

I try user HttpPostedFileBase in My Controller but not work.
Should I convert File to byte array before call Controller Function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at these:
[File Upload Using Angular JS and ASP.NET MVC 5](https://www.codeproject.com/tips/878730/file-upload-using-angularjs-and-asp-net-mvc)
[File Upload with Angular and ASP.NET MVC 4](http://codehandbook.org/file-upload-using-angularjs-and-asp-net-mvc-4/)

If you're not uploading large images, you could also convert them to `Base64` strings and post them to server.